# iterate over a vector thats defined as a typedef C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct as follows

```
struct pins
{
    PType pintypes;
    GType Grouptypes
};
```

where PType and GType are defined as

```
typedef std::vector< pInfo > PType;
typedef std::vector<gInfo> GType;
```

where pInfo and gInfo are classes with sample members as

```
struct pInfo {
    std::string pinNumber;
    std::string pinName;
};
```

Now I am comparing two PinInfos from pins variable.I want to see if given two pins, they have exactly the same pintypes.

I am trying as follows.

```
for (std::vector<pInfo>::const_iterator prim1Pin = pins.pinTypes.begin(); prim1Pin != pins.pinTypes.end(); prim1Pin++)
    {
        if (bRet)
        {
            std::vector<pInfo>::const_iterator prim2pin = std::find(prim2.pinTypes.begin(), prim2.pinTypes.end(), (*prim1Pin).pinNumber);
            if (prim2pin!=prim2.pinTypes.end())
            {
                bRet &= ((*prim2pin).PinNumber== (*prim1Pin).PinNumber&& (*prim2pin).pinName == (*prim1Pin).pinName)                    
            }
            else
                bRet &= false;
        }
    }
```

when I compile this I get the following error in `algorithm.h` file

`Error  C2678   binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'pInfo' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm    41`
Not sure whats wrong with this.
I am using some version less than C++ 11.

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with typedefs, remove the typedefs.

Comment: its a huge file with 11K lines of code. removing typedefs where ever they are used in that one would be terribly laborious

Comment: That is your problem. You need to find ways to understand your own code.

Comment: Isn't there a smart way to iterate and compare what I want??

Answer (score 2):

In your call to `find`, you're iterating over a container that holds a bunch of `pinType` objects, while you're searching for a `string` value.  The compiler will need an overload of `operator==` that takes a `pinType` on the left and a `string` on the right.

So you'll want to either provide that operation, or define a lambda or comparison class to handle it.